# Unable to connect to a SQL Server database remotely

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, tcp

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition set up on a Windows Server 2008 R2 edition and although I was able to get into the database locally via SQL Server Management Studio (using my server `name\MSSQLSERVER`), I was unable to get in there remotely (using `IP\MSSQLSERVER`).

I have turned off the firewall for Windows (no other firewall installed) and turned on all 4 protocols for SQL Server (Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP and  VIA) and has turned on every single service in the SQL Server Management Studio with no luck.

Could you please help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, I am able to ping my server from the machine I was trying to connect remotely into without any problem.

Comment: Is "SQL Server Browser" service running?  You probably don't need the VIA protocol turned on, btw.  More info about SQL Server Browswer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed after reinstall the whole system and open port 1433 for TCP connections.

Answer (score 7):

enable TCP/IP, Shared Memory and Named Pipes from all prorams> sql 2012 > configuration tools > sql server configuration manager > expand sql server network configuration > protocols for sql2012r2de

Answer (score 6):

Did you check the following?

1. Configure SQL Server to allow remote connections
2. Configure TCP/IP connection enabled and on IP Address tab specific to Ip Address change to Active -> Yes, Enabled -> Yes
3. Add/Check Firewall policy is open for port 1433(Default) or specific port according to your sql server listner port

Comment: +1 for reminding me about Windows Firewall.  For some reason after installing SQL on a new Azure VM the firewall rule never got created so all inbound connections failed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you **sure** you're connecting to the **developer** instance?? From the instance name, it would appear that you have a SQL Server **Express** edition installed....

Check by running this SQL statement:

```
SELECT  
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition')
```

SQL Server Express does not allow remote connections by default - see this [Microsoft KB to learn how to enable remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277).

Comment: It might be something is messed up there so I actually did a reinstall of the entire OS to get rid of all those crap...I will let you know if I still have this problem. Thanks!